# Protect the data at the bottom of the page from being hidden under the fixed div?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a response website.
I have a lots of data on a page, and at the bottom of page there is a fixed div, the data in this div is dynamic some time it has 2 lines some time 3 that may vary.

To protect the data at the bottom of the page from being hidden under the fixed div I want some empty space at the end of the page?

here is the code.

```
<style>
    .screen-bottom-fixed {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color:aqua;
        padding-top: 8px;
    }
    .section-1 {
        text-align: center;
        background-color: red;
    }
    .section-2 {
        text-align: center;
        background-color:chartreuse;
    }
</style>

<div class="page">
    <div class="1">
        about 200 lines of text here.....   
    </div>
    <div class="screen-bottom-fixed">
        <div class="section-1">
            We have some lines of dynamic date here 11111.....
        </div>
        <div class="section-2">
            We have some more dynamic date here 22222.......
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also suggest me good approach to have fixed data at the bottom of screen and the data on the page is safe from being hidden under the div.

Comment: How about js solution?

Comment: I will prefer css solution if there exists, js solution is also welcome.

Comment: ok, i have added js solution

Comment: @Syed if you want work arround with css then go with this https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/z6a1otgm/3/

Comment: @Leothelion, i guess your solution will not work in situation where fixed block can change height dinamically.

Comment: @Syed, did my answer help you?

Comment: @Kison well i have tried that too and then gave in comment. Please check at your own and if you find any issue let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that you not added js in tags for question, but js it`s first that comes to my head in this situation.

First add empty block before **screen-bottom-fixed** block

```
<div class="separator"><!-- empty block --></div>
```

Then with js you can control it height

```
$('.separator').height($('.screen-bottom-fixed').height());
```

Also you can recalculate it on window resize event

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    $('.separator').height($('.screen-bottom-fixed').height());
});
```

Here is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kison/9rv2o7py/)